# check password returning false after entering the right password

Tags: django-models, django-authentication, graphql-js

I have a  problem authentication a user in my program their is already a custom user model but i am tasked to create a separate user model in a new app that will track users usin the api or have access_it. but when i create a user and decide to authenticate the user it send me invalid password
below is my model and mutation

below is my models and mutation

```
class Api_Client(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column="Api_Client_ID", primary_key=True)
    uuid = models.CharField(db_column="Api_Client_UUID", max_length=36, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    access_token = models.TextField(db_column="client_acess_token", blank=True, null=True)
    token_expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column="token_expiry_date", blank=True, null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # Add is_active field
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        Group,
        verbose_name=_('groups'),
        blank=True,
        related_name='api_client_groups',  # Add a unique related_name
        help_text=_(
            'The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions '
            'granted to each of their groups.'),
        related_query_name='api_client',
    )
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Permission,
        verbose_name=_('user permissions'),
        blank=True,
        related_name='api_client_user_permissions',  # Add a unique related_name
        help_text=_('Specific permissions for this user.'),
        related_query_name='api_client',
    )
    private_key = models.CharField(
        db_column="Private_Key",
        max_length=256,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text="The private key is actually a password salt",
    )
    
    # You don't need to define the `objects` manager if you're using the default one from AbstractUser

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []  # 'password' is automatically required

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:  # If creating a new instance
            self.set_password(self.password)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = "Api_Client"
```

file class CreateApiClient(graphene.Mutation):
class Arguments:
input_data = Api_ClientInpuType(required=True)
Output = graphene.String

```
@classmethod
def mutate(cls, root, info, input_data=None):
    try:
        if info.context.user is AnonymousUser:
            raise ValidationError(_("mutation.authentication_required"))
        
        new_user = Api_Client(username=input_data['username'],  is_staff=input_data['is_staff'])
        new_user.set_password(input_data['password'])  # Set the password
        new_user.save()

        # Return the mutation result with the created user
        return new_user
    except Exception as exc:
        return [{
            # No user created, so set to None
            "message": _("api_client_mutation failed to create"),
            "detail": str(exc)
        }]
```

class GenerateAccessToken(graphene.Mutation):
class Arguments:
username = graphene.String(required=True)
password = graphene.String(required=True)

```
Output = graphene.String

@staticmethod
def mutate(root, info, username, password):
    try:
        # Authenticate the user using Django's authenticate function
        user = Api_Client.objects.get(username=username)
        print("Authenticated User:", user)  # Debug print
        
        if not user.check_password(password):
            raise Exception('Invalid credentials')
        
        # If authentication is successful, generate a JWT token
        token = get_token(user)  # Replace with your actual function

        return GenerateAccessToken(token=token)  # Return the token as mutation output
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to generate access token: {str(e)}")
```

Comment: Please *don't* use `self.set_password(self.password)` in the `save` method: there is a good reason *not* to do this, this will hash the password *a second* time.